# siunitx use \per with: \cubic\metre\per\hour not centered

Tags: siunitx

I used `siunitx` package to display: cubic meter per hour like:

```
\SI{}{\cubic\metre\per\hour}
```

but the print seems to be somehow not centered. Is this the way it should look or am I using the package wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not centered". To me, the numerator and denominator terms look perfectly centered...

Comment: mh, than it is just me seeing ghosts...

Comment: @Redfox87678 Currently the `h` is centred below `m^3`. What output do you desire? The `h` centred under the `m` (without taking the `^3` into account)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like you've set the option `per-mode=fraction` of the `siunitx` package. (The default is `per-mode=reciprocal`, by the way.) If the resulting fraction expression looks asymmetric or unbalanced to you -- it doesn't to me, but impressions are subjective -- you may want to switch to either `per-mode=reciprocal` or `per-mode=symbol`. One advantage of the latter two options is that the symbols `m` and `h` are rendered at the size of the surrounding running text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "\SI" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\SI[per-mode=fraction]{500}{\cubic\metre\per\hour},
\SI[per-mode=reciprocal]{500}{\cubic\metre\per\hour}, % this is the default
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{500}{\cubic\metre\per\hour}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```